# Roboust Human detection and tracking in a crowded area

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, blob, background-subtraction

I am working on an application where I need to detect and track people in a crowded indoor area(like a mall). Right now I am using the OpenCV Background Subtraction class(MOG2) to detect blobs and a Kalman filter and Hungarian Algorithm for tracking(based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fW5TmAtAXM)).

The issues I'm having are:

1. The blobs merging together when two people come close to each other
2. Parts of the person not getting detected which leads to false and multiple detections on a person
3. The background subtraction itself results in too many false detections.

I would like to know your suggestions to improve this and any solutions to fix these problems? Is there an alternate way to detect humans?I am not using HOG because I didn't get detections unless the entire body of the person was in the frame, and it resulted in false detections as well.

Thanks in advance!

BTW, I'm using OpenCV 3.1,C++

edit:

This what I mean by false detections with HOG:

[image]

[image: Person not detected when only half is body is present in the frame]

[image]

Comment: Please change tags. This question is not related to C++.

Comment: Can you please add some images? HOG is currently one of the SOTAs out there and arguably the best one, if that doesn't work, few example images will help tackle the problem

Comment: @RickM. please check the edits

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of the work done by Rodrigo Benenson.

[How Far are We from Solving Pedestrian Detection?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01237)

[Ten Years of pedestrian detection](http://rodrigob.github.io/documents/2014_eccvw_ten_years_of_pedestrian_detection_with_supplementary_material.pdf)

It's a really good starting point for pedestrian detection and understand what are the different approaches that has been used in the last decade.